# How to append current time stamp in IBM managed file transfer (MFT) without milliseconds?

Tags: ibm-mq, ntfs-mft

I was trying to incorporate current time stamp parameter in IBM managed file transfer (MFT) without milliseconds using $(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').which is giving a constant value always.

Can you suggest any idea to have a dynamic timestamp

Tried it in different ways as below

$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')  - gave constant datetime always

$(date +'%Y%m%d%h%m%s')  - got (date +%Y%m%d%h%m%s)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the use case? Where in IBM MQ MFT you are trying to incorporate time stamp - which command? is it fteCreateTransfer or some other?